# SecureSocial login after signup

Tags: playframework, securesocial

I'm using Play Framework 2.1 with SecureSocial.
I have my own templates, UserService, and UsernamePasswordProvider/FacebookProvider.

I dont use SecureSocial to register my users, but I use it to login and handle sessions.
How can I make people be logged in after registration, so in my Java code ?

I tried to use `Authenticator.create(...)`

```
securesocial.core.Authenticator.create(Scala.orNull(securesocial.core.UserService.find(new securesocial.core.UserId(newUser.getId(),"wimhauserpass"))));
```

but I cant use `UserService.find()`, it tells me it must be static ...

I'm gonna implement another Provider dedicated to retrieve credentials from the RegisterForm, and call

```
securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticate("userpassregister");
```

Any better idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you have a custom signup controller and after successful signup the user shall be logged in.

We also had this case in a play2 java app with securesocial, and our CustomRegistrationController.handleSignUp method looks s.th. like this:

```java
public Result handleSignUp(final String token) {
    // verify token, validate form, fill user from form etc.
    ...

    // save user in userService, delete token
    userService.doSave(user);
    userService.doDeleteToken(token);

    // login user
    final Either<Error, Authenticator> result = Authenticator.create(user);
    if (result.isLeft()) {
        // add some msg to flash, redirect to login
        ...
        return redirect(RoutesHelper.login());
    }

    // Add the auth cookie to response
    final play.api.mvc.Cookie authCookie = result.right().get().toCookie();
    response().setCookie(authCookie.name(), authCookie.value(),
        (Integer)Scala.orNull(authCookie.maxAge()), authCookie.path(),
        Scala.orNull(authCookie.domain()), authCookie.secure(), authCookie.httpOnly());

    // Add some success message
    ...
    return redirect(routes.UserSignUpController.signUpConfirmation());
}
```

I hope this answers your question.